# Interacting the JSP page with the Servlet doGet() method through AJAX call

Tags: java, ajax, angularjs, servlets

Am doing the JAVA code found below, to call the servlet doGet() method from JSP page through AJAX call.

Here is my AJAX call..
      Am sending the clicked text captured by ng-click of Angular js as a querystring to Servlet's doGet() method .

In my JSP file,

```
  $scope.requestFunc = function (clickData) {

       var urlquerystring =  clickData; 
       jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/Charts/testExecution/"+"?"+ urlquerystring,

         dataType: 'html',
          success: function(respnsedata)
          {
            window.location.assign(respnsedata);    
          }
       });
  }
```

In my Servlet's doGet() method,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.err.println("In TestExecutionESO servlet..");


        String teamnametextfield= req.getParameter("teamnametextfield");
        System.out.println("Teamname is.."+teamnametextfield);

        try {
            dcmanager = DataCollectorManager.getInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String selectedteam= req.getQueryString();

        String testexeclistofobjectsjson = null;

        if(selectedteam!=null)
        {

            String release=selectedteam.replace("%20"," ").toString();

        testexecutionobjlist = dcmanager.getRallyDcMgr().gettestExecutionobjlist(release);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        testexeclistofobjectsjson = gson.toJson(testexecutionobjlist);

        System.out.println(testexecutionobjlist);
        System.out.println(testexeclistofobjectsjson);

        req.getSession().setAttribute("testexeclistofobjectsjson", testexeclistofobjectsjson);

        resp.sendRedirect("TestExecutionESO.jsp");

}
```

Am getting the querystring perfectly..After the processing, I will do SetAttribute() and redirect to next JSP page..
  Redirect is not working..

Here is my error code,
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS..

http://10.112.81.95:9000/Charts/testExecution/TestExecutionESO.jsp.... Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please help me resolve the problem..
how to redirect to next JSP page by doing the setAttribute() .??

Answer (score 0):

```
resp.sendRedirect("TestExecutionESO.jsp");
```

This is the culprit in your code. when you call sendRedirect(), it will issue a 302 response containing the location-header, URI of the new resource. When the browser sees this header, it will issue a new request for that new URI.

All of this works well for a synchronous request but in case of AJAX calls, we use an XMLHttpRequest, which will not handle redirects so well.

I'd suggest you to use a RequestDispatcher instead to forward to the JSP like this

```
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("path-to-ur-jsp");
rd.forward(req,res);
```